# How do you increment or create unique ID in CouchBase?

Tags: php, unique, couchbase

I'm having problem figuring out how to create unique keys each time I insert data into my PHP application, MySQL users are used to auto-incrementing the index key but I can't seem to find a technique to do that in CouchBase :(

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a some information to Avsej answer:
As you can see in the CounterId patter the program is using the Couchbase increment operation, that is documented here for the PHP SDK:

- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-php-1.1/api-reference-update.html#table-couchbase-sdk_php_increment

And some detailed information about increment in the Couchbase developer guide:
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/cb-incr-decr.html

So with this operation you can create "sequence like" ID for your application.

Comment: Awesome, I've figured that out. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

For autoincrementing ID you can use once operation http://couchbasemodels.com/patterns/counter_id. Also you can use some random unique ID generator