# Spring Data Couchbase: Automatic ID generation

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I'm setting up a Document with the `@Id` annotation and in my tests I get a `MappingException` because the Id is not set when creating a new document. Is spring-data + couchbase unable to automatically assign an ID for new documents?

Answer (score 4):

There is no auto-generation of IDs in Couchbase, so you need to set one.

Keep in mind that Couchbase can store heterogeneous data in the same `Bucket`, so by default if you have several types of entities, they'll end up in the same storage unit. Therefore if you have eg. `User` and `Product` entities, creating and saving a `User` which `@Id` is "foo" then a `Product` also id-ed "foo" will end up overwriting the `User` with the `Product`.

What I mean is, you have to provide the `@Id` **and** make sure no ID collide, even across entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

As of commit [069ceea](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/commit/069ceea65c42bcf8ca3f845781363681878a8927) spring-data-couchbase seems to include support for autogenerating keys using generated keys by properties or unique UUIDs. See [HERE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/069ceea65c42bcf8ca3f845781363681878a8927/src/main/asciidoc/autokeygeneration.adoc) for documentation on how to use it.

Comment: I couldn't get this working. Posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998493/how-are-ids-autogenerated-in-spring-data-couchbase Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer.

```
@Document
public class User {
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = UNIQUE)
     private String id;
     ...
}
```

as per
[this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/069ceea65c42bcf8ca3f845781363681878a8927/src/main/asciidoc/autokeygeneration.adoc)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, there's a UUID Generator available with Couchbase Java SDK that can help you.

There's a discussion about UUID [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229888/generate-unique-uint32-id-for-couchbase).

Comment: yes, using Couchbase's atomic counter documents can serve the purpose of generating a sequence for IDs. Unless using the same counter in every type of document, you'll still need to eg. use a prefix to ensure uniqueness of the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the UUID as unique using Java. This will generate UUID by Java. Can be used as unique in Couchbase PK.

```
@Document
public class BasicEntity {

@Id
@Field
private String _id;

/**
 * @return the _id
 */
public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

/**
 */
public void set_id() {
    this._id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   }

}
```