# How are ids autogenerated in spring data couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, auto-generate, spring-data-couchbase

I want to create autogeneration of IDs to my documents in spring data couchbase. Spring docs has steps for this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration

Here is my code:

```
@Document
public class User {
     @Id 
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES, delimiter = ".")
     private String id;
     @IdPrefix(order=0)
     private String userPrefix;
     @IdSuffix(order=0)
     private String userSuffix;
     ...
}
```

I've a repository created for this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

}
```

Now, when I try to save a record to the user bucket(userRepository.save(user)), I get following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Document ID must not be null or empty.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.document.AbstractDocument.<init>(AbstractDocument.java:53) ~[java-client-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.document.RawJsonDocument.<init>(RawJsonDocument.java:149) ~[java-client-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.document.RawJsonDocument.create(RawJsonDocument.java:80) ~[java-client-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.encodeAndWrap(CouchbaseTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.access$400(CouchbaseTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate$11.doInBucket(CouchbaseTemplate.java:591) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate$11.doInBucket(CouchbaseTemplate.java:586) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.execute(CouchbaseTemplate.java:536) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.doPersist(CouchbaseTemplate.java:586) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.save(CouchbaseTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.save(CouchbaseTemplate.java:228) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.SimpleCouchbaseRepository.save(SimpleCouchbaseRepository.java:86) ~[spring-data-couchbase-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

...

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring Data Couchbase version 2.2.9 which does not support auto generating keys.

If you want autogenerated keys you should use a later version (For example 3.0.2)

See here for latest versions and instructions: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/

Comment: I don't think this is the case. If you look at the 2.2.9.RELEASE's documentation, the docs mention auto generation of keys. Maybe missing auto configuration?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.2.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration

Comment: Actually it seems you are right, will remove this answer shortly. :)

Comment: Btw, I think 2.2.9's documentation has an issue. The annotations are there but they have no impact on the key generation. When I look at the PR, it's tagged as if it was merged in 3.0.x branches. So, someone from the Spring Data Couchbase team needs to jump in. :) Please don't remove your comment as it's one of the very few comments that led me to the right path.